# Laravel eloquent relationship 'with' keyword

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have a table called `rides` where I save `user_id`,and `driver_id`. 
so the `rides` table is `id|user_id|driver_id|ticket_id|created_at|updated_at`.
All users(client,driver) are saved in `users` table. While retrieving the a row from the `rides` table I write

```
$rides = Ride::with('client','driver')->get();
```

Relationships:

```
public function client()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id');
}

public function driver()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'driver_id');
}
```

Now the problem is when a row is retrieved, Only the information of client comes. `driver` is `null`.
After swapping the parameters `driver` and `client`

```
$rides = Ride::with('driver','client')->get();
```

driver information comes, and client becomes null.. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the relationship with both keys:

```
public function driver()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'driver_id', 'id');
}
```